# How to use old style numbers with xelibertine

Tags: libertine, oldstylenums

I use the package:

```
\usepackage{xelibertine}
```

It works fine. But I do not know how to make the numbers old style. So I tried

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}
```

But it's not working.

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: You may try `libertineotf`: `\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}]{libertineotf}` should be the desired option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `xelibertine` package is quite old and unsupported. I find this in the SourceForge site of LinuxLibertine.org

> [Linux Libertine 5.0 is not working with the old xelibertine.sty.
>   Will be an update soon?](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=590374&aid=3308266&group_id=89513)

The up-to-date interface to Linux Libertine for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX is the package `libertineotf`.

In order to get oldstyle digits, you can call it by

```
\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}]{libertineotf}
```

Comment: Do you know if this is still the standard way to invoke oldstyle figures? I’m currently just using `\usepackage{polyglossia}` with `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}`, but it does not show oldstyle figures. Unfortunately, they are not mentioned in the package documentation. I do not currently use the `libertineotf` package.
edit: I found the `[Numbers=OldStyle]` option. Thank you :)

Comment: @Philipp Support of Libertine has changed through the years. `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}[Numbers=OldStyle]` should be the current best way.